# Lottery question (Cumulative Distribution)

Tags: probability

A lottery game consists of matching three numbers drawn (without replacement)
from a set of 15 numbers. Let X denote the random variable representing
the numbers on your tickets that match the winning numbers. Find
the cumulative distribution of X.

Now the solution shows p(0) = 220/455.

How? with p(0) you are assuming none of your numbers match the winning 3 numbers so wouldn't that be (3C0)/(15C3) = 1/455??

Comment: No, it would be $\frac{{}_3C_0 \, {}_{12}C_3}{{}_{15}C_3}$.

Answer (score 1):

$P(0)$ is the probability that none of your numbers match the 3 numbers selected (I assume order does not matter).

You know that there are ${15 \choose 3} = 455$ ways to draw 3 numbers from 15 numbers without replacement. Now you seem to claim that there is only 1 combination that is not matching any of the drawn 3 numbers, since you say that $P(0) = 1/455$. Surely if you think about it in this way, you can see that this cannot be true. So how many ways can we choose 3 numbers so that none of the 3 selected/drawn are part of our numbers?

Well, it's simple, we just have $15-3 =12$ numbers to choose from (instead of the initial 15). And we can choose any of these 12 numbers (without replacement). So how many ways do we have? ${12 \choose 3} = 220$. Hence $P(0) = 220/455$

Comment: *In summary:* We seek the probability for selecting zero from the three winning numbers, **and** *three from the twelve non-winning numbers*, when drawing three from all fifteen numbers with neither replacement nor bias.$$\dfrac{{}^{3}\mathrm C_0{\cdot}^{12}\mathrm C_3}{{}^{15}\mathrm C_3}$$